# Karate - input field/textarea clear field is not working properly

Tags: automated-tests, karate

Using Karate I am not able to clear field (input, textarea) properly:

```
<input name="title" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. My MacBook Key" value="">
```

1) insert to input field with id=title is OK.

```
retry().input('#title', 'something')
```

Everything is written to field. OK.

2) I need to clear the field. I use following:

```
retry().clear('#title')
```

Field seems to be deleted after this action (text in input field is not visible).

3) But when I use input again

```
retry().input('#title', 'new')
```

In field is displayed: somethingnew. It seems that first string was not properly deleted and strings are merged together.
It happens for input/text area fields.

Could you help me please? Any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `value()` or JS directly instead of `clear()`:

```
* value('#title', '')
```

Or:

```
* script('#title', "_.value = ''")
```

Comment: When I use script possibility, it works fine in that case. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @peter thomas, 
What is the difference between functions input() and value(set). 
input did not work for me on IE 11, but value(set) worked.

Comment: @Rajeev impossible to say without seeing the html. most likely some fancy JS on the page. difference is the second option forces the DOM to be updated via JS

Comment: Its simple html (textbox for user and password and a login button), no JS. 
With Input() following error was generated,  "error" : "no such element", "message" : "Unable to find element with css selector == #loginUsername". 
It worked perfectly when I replaced Input() with value(set).

Comment: @Rajeev I don't believe you :) follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Created issue https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1731

Answer (score 2):

First we need to focus on the web element

- focus(webElement)

Then clear the input field/text area on the browser, use clear()

- clear(webElement)

To clear the value from DOM, we are using Key.CLEAR

- input(webElement, Key.CLEAR)

Finally insert your value/custom value into the input field as below

- input(webElement, "Insert your value")